# Matlab - plot and color samples based on data

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, colormap

I have the following data:

- dataMatrix (20x210): 20 samples with 210 variables each
- wavelength: 1 row of 210 variables describing the wavelength number
- concentrations: concentration value for each sample (20 rows and 1 column)

I usually plot the data in a normal way:

```
plot(wavelength, dataMatrix)
```

[image]

But what I want is to plot and color each sample according to the concentration value taking into account the rest, color based on data. I think it is something to do with colormap. The result would be something like this:

[image]

Is there any easy way to do this using Matlab?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice question (y) same problem here

Comment: This might come in handy : http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/15/colors-for-your-multi-line-plots/

Answer (score 0):

[`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzitot-2) accepts line property including line color, like

```
plot(wavelength, dataMatrix, 'Color', [0,0,0.1])
```

[`colormap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#budgl13) can convert built-in color maps to RGB matrices, like

```
nlines = length(concentrations);
cmap = hsv(nlines)
```

mapping concentration to color could be as easy as sorting the numbers

```
c = concentrations - min(concentrations);
c = ceil( c/max(c)*nlines );
```

finally, draw each line separately

```
for ii = 1:nlines
    plot(wavelength, dataMatrix(ii,:), 'Color', cmap(c(ii),:))
    hold on
end
hold off
```